# Is the Fragments backstack also restored when the activity is recreated after its process being killed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Since the fragments back stack is managed by the host activity, if this activity is destroyed by the system (because the system needs more memory somewhere else) and recreated after because the user came back, will the fragments back stack state be recreated also by the system?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score -1):

I dont believe the fragment backstack is saved by default. However you can request it be added with this:

```
FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack()
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I am using FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(). But the fragments backstack is not the same as the activitys backstack. As far as I know the fragments back stack is managed by the activity that hosts the fragments. If that activity is killed, where's the fragments backstack?